# How can I set specific item in an ArrayList, without getting the OutOfBounds error?

Tags: java, plugins

I am trying to code a Trade plugin for a game. My idea is that a player sends request to another player, and if the other player accepts, then each side has to choose an item to trade.

I have 4 ArrayLists:
To store the requesters, to store the requested, to store requester's chosen item and to store requested's chosen item. The problem is that if multiple players trade at the same time, I can't just add the item to the List, because it can match with somebody else's trade. I tried to do this:

```
requesterItems.set(requesterIndex, clicked);
```

Where requesterIndex is the index of the requester in the other list and clicked is the item that's selected.

I know why there is an error, but I can't think of a workaround. The problem is that the List is empty and there is no element at this index. How can I add an element there without touching other spots in the list?

Comment: why are you using the same lists for all transactions? this sounds like a bad design IMHO

Comment: Because I must store items somehow so I can put them in player's inventories when both sides accept. What is your idea?

Comment: You could work with a map instead. Also I would recommend you to rethink your solution. I would recommend that you create something like a Trade-Class where you store the information of a single trade.

Comment: You can check for number of elements in an array, and work from there.

Comment: I recommend a solution like the one @Christian mentioned

Comment: I will consider doing something like this, thanks for the fast responses!

Comment: Since you're in multithreading environment best approach would be ConcurrentHashMap, which is best trade-safe map in java.

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid to work with concrete indexes if possible and work with objects instead.

As already mentioned in the comments, I would recommend an own class with a HashMap. Heres a bit of code like I would do it (**!Not tested!**):

```
private HashMap<YourPlayerClass, List<YourItemClass>> playerItemMap = new HashMap<>();

private void tradeItems(YourPlayerClass p_player1, YourPlayerClass p_player2,
                        YourItemClass p_itemOfPlayer1, YourItemClass p_itemOfPlayer2)
{
     List<YourItemClass> itemsOfPlayer1 = playerItemMap.get(p_player1);
     List<YourItemClass> itemsOfPlayer2 = playerItemMap.get(p_player2);

     //Carry out the trade for player 1
     itemsOfPlayer1.remove(p_itemOfPlayer1);
     itemsOfPlayer1.add(p_itemOfPlayer2);
     playerItemMap.put(p_player1, itemsOfPlayer1); //Not sure if this put is necessary

     //Carry out the trade for player 2
     itemsOfPlayer2.remove(p_itemOfPlayer2);
     itemsOfPlayer2.add(p_itemOfPlayer1);
     playerItemMap.put(p_player2, itemsOfPlayer2); //Not sure if this put is necessary
}
```

So theres a HashMap with the player as key and his/her items as List-value.

The code example isn't failure safe. I would recommend to add some check if the items are really in this list to avoid errors. Like:

```
if(itemsOfPlayer1.contains(p_itemOfPlayer1))
{
    //Carry out the trade
}
else
    System.err.println("Player 1 tried to trade an item which wasn't in his/her inventory! Shouldn't be possible!");
```

I hope this helps a bit to solve your problem, let me know if I've got you wrong! Good luck!